# Dependency injection in entity classes with code first

Tags: dependency-injection, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm trying to figure out a way to handle dependency injection in entity framework code first.

I stumbled upon an [article](http://rogeralsing.com/2009/05/30/entity-framework-4-entity-dependency-injection/) that uses ObjectStateManager though I don't think it's available in code first, so I'm looking for something similar where I could inject (property injection) an object into a newly created/fetched entity, or maybe there's a different way?

I'm using Autofac as the di container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do DI like this

```
 public class YourContext : DbContext
 {
    protected ObjectContext ObjectContext
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        }
    }

    public YourContext(string connectionString):base(connectionString)
    {
        ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += ObjectMaterialized;
    }

    void ObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do property injection here using e.Entity
    }
 }
```